# How do I redirect to google from tomcat server?

Tags: javascript, jsp, tomcat

I'm trying to write an jsp application using apache tomcat server. I need a button's onclick to redirect to google. When I give -

```
onclick="window.open('www.google.com');"
```

It opens a new window with

```
http://localhost:8080/LiveSearch/www.google.com
```

How do I make it open a window with just 'www.google.com' as url?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";`. This will act as if you were simply opening a new URL.

Comment: I actually tried that before opening a new window. That too redirected to the same url I mentiones above.